# Activate fans from GRUB

Tags: linux, grub, macbook-pro, grub2, macbook-pro-retina

Is it possible to activate fans at full speed from GRUB2 boot loader ?

I'm running on Macbook Pro retina 2015 and if I forget to boot and let my grub screen hanging, my computer starts getting pretty hot (over 88°C).

The solution would be to activate the fans when GRUB starts to prevent overheating. Is that possible ?

Comment: Usually, fan speed can be set in the BIOS. Can you do that?

Comment: @Darren I'm on Macbook Pro, so it's EFI only, I don't have any BIOS unfortunately.

Comment: OK, for BIOS read EFI. There is still a configuration utility for it, n'est-ce pas?

Comment: @Darren There isn't really. You can just set the startup disk in the NVRAM using either bless on OSX or efibootmgr on Linux and then it loads the EFI image directly on boot. There isn't any settings menu like on a PC with a BIOS.

Comment: @Darren I can `modprobe applesmc` module on Linux to change the fan speed by modifying `/sys/devices/platform/applesmc.768/fan1_min`. Can this be done with GRUB ? It seems however that this setting is persistent across reboot, but I don't want to have my fans running at full speed all the time when I boot my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a proper answer, just a workaround.

Don't let GRUB2 wait indefinitely. Let it wait a while and either

- boot a default OS that will provide fan control; or
- shutdown.

---

This is how you can configure the latter workaround on Kubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. Adjust this example to your OS and your needs.

1. Add a proper menu entry. The right file is `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`. For clarity I'm pasting the file with its header:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   exec tail -n +3 $0
   # This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
   # menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
   # the 'exec tail' line above.

   menuentry Shutdown --class shutdown {
   halt
   }
   ```

   Note: `--class shutdown` [is optional](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/163985/108618).
2. Configure this entry as default. Edit `/etc/default/grub` and modify/create the following options:

   ```
   GRUB_DEFAULT=Shutdown
   GRUB_TIMEOUT=30
   ```
3. Run `update-grub`.

Now if you forget to boot and let your GRUB screen hanging, your computer will halt after 30 seconds.

Comment: That's actually a very good answer ! I'll add that to all my GRUB setups so it doesn't overheat and/or drain all battery if left for a while.